# adding element in a list throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, list, exception, addition

My code throws this:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range.
>   Parameter name: index error

When it finds an element in a list that have a count less that a specific number. any ideas on how to correct the code?

I've added debug.log code everywhere to determine exactly where the error happens, because no error is underlined by Visual Studio.

```
List<int> emptyRows = new List<int>();
for (int j = 0; j < gridPositions.Count; j++) // try to find if a row is still empty
                {
                    Debug.Log("gridPositions[" + j + "].Count is " + gridPositions[j].Count);
                    Debug.Log("columns are" + columns);
                    if (gridPositions[j].Count == columns)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("trying to add to emptyrows");
                        emptyRows.Add(j);
                        Debug.Log("added to emptyrows and its count is " + emptyRows.Count);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.Log("found an occupied row at row " + j);
//ERROR STRIKES HERE
                    }
                    Debug.Log("emptyRows is " + emptyRows[j]);
                    Debug.Log("emptyRows count is " + emptyRows.Count);
                }
```

I expect the emptyRows to track and record all unoccupied rows, but when it fills an occupied row, it not proceeds whit the for loop and stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only adding to emptyRows  if (gridPositions[j].Count == columns)

But you are accessing the emptyRows[j] on every value of j

So the emptyRows ends up having less items then the value of j is

Comment: I'm quite a beginner, so I don't know how the architecture of c# works. do you think that removing                     Debug.Log("emptyRows is " + emptyRows[j]); solve the problem? Or i need to change how i'm adding elements on emptyrows?

Comment: removing this will solve the problem. if you don't need that just remove it Debug.Log("emptyRows is " + emptyRows[j]);